# C2DM or XMPP -- what is better for push notifications

Tags: android, xmpp, android-c2dm

I am building a web based chat application like gtalk.
What should I use among C2DM and XMPP. Is there any other alternative?
What is the failure-success ratio of C2DM.

### Thanks

Answer (score 1):

C2DM is best, because it is Google server and also apis are available for C2DM in Android.

Any third party server you use, Android device will communication to C2DM server only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am already using C2DM in one of my applications. The failure percentage of notifications is 20-30%.The notifications generally get delayed.
Anyone having xmpp experience? Please guide

Thanks,